# Data as JSON Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i have a search in which it gets data from `table` `candidates`

My Search Code

```
public function advance(Request $request)
    {
    $data1 = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>Admin::where('id','=', session('LoggedUser'))->first()];
    $data = \DB::table('candidates');
    if( $request->name){
        $data = $data->where('name', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->name . "%");
    }
     if( $request->location){
        $data = $data->where('location', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->location . "%");
    }
     if( $request->key_skills){
        $data = $data->where('key_skills', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->key_skills . "%");
    }
    if( $request->gender){
        $data = $data->where('gender', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->gender . "%");
    }
     if( $request->pref_loc){
        $data = $data->where('pref_loc', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->pref_loc . "%");
    }
    if( $request->phoneno){
        $data = $data->where('phoneno', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->phoneno . "%");
    }
     if( $request->email){
        $data = $data->where('email', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->email . "%");
    }
    $min_np = $request->min_np;
    $max_np = $request->max_np;
     if ($min_np || $max_np) {
     $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(notice_period,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= {$min_np}");
     $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(notice_period,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) <= {$max_np}");
 }
    $min_ctc = $request->min_ctc;
    $max_ctc = $request->max_ctc;
    
 
    if ($min_ctc || $max_ctc) {
     $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salary,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= {$min_ctc}");
     $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salary,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) <= {$max_ctc}");
 }

     if ($request->min_exp || $request->max_exp) {
     $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(experrience,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= {$request->min_exp}");
     $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(experrience,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) <= {$request->max_exp}");
 }
    // $dataa = $data+;
    $data = $data->paginate(10);
    $data2 = $data->total();
    $dataa = $data->toJson();

    $data4 = \DB::table('admins')->get();
    $setting = DB::select('select * from logo where id=?',[1]);

    return view('search', compact('data2','data4','setting','dataa'))->with('data',$data);
}
```

Now i want this `$data` to be converted into an 'Array or JSON'

but when i try this `$data->toJson();` it give me this data in `pagination` with all pages link & paginated data

but i want all data
in a `Array or JSON`

**Note - I want all data at once bcz to export the data into csv file**

[image]

Comment: well, why you call paginate if you want all data at once, just call `->get()` then

Comment: @Lk77 basically paginated data is show on blade page & i want all data at once to **export the data into csv file**

Comment: then delay the paginate call after you have done the export, or better make another controller method to do the export, because it will defeat the whole purpose of paginate

Comment: @Lk77 no the export function is separated from this search i only need that all data

Comment: you could move everything to a separate function getData, with a parameter that enable or disable pagination, so you do getData(false) in the export for full data and getData(true) for paginated data for your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the pagination don't use `$data = $data->paginate(10);`
instead use `$data = $data->get();`

Comment: i want pagination & data both

Comment: `$data->get();` this worked for me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://scoutapm.com/blog/php-json_encode-serialize-php-objects-to-json, you can try this:

```
$dataJson = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: still data in pagination. i want all data without pagination. check updated question